# Drawing graphs in Java, which are updated regularly

Tags: java, user-interface, graph

I am trying to create an application which monitors the price of petrol over time. Currently my application has a GUI which displays information as text-- so as a list. 
However, I now want to add a display which will show the prices graphically. The user can choose to show more than one type of petrol and the graphs are updated automatically every 5 seconds.

I am confused as to how to go about drawing a very simple scatterplot in java. Can anyone make suggestions

Comment: is it web based application or desktop app?

Comment: You could roll your own, but there are third party libraries that do just this sort of thing such as JFreeChart. You might want to check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;

public class Scatterplot extends JFrame {

    private List points = new ArrayList();

    public Scatterplot() {
        super("Scatterplot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        points.add(new Point2D.Float(2, 4));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(16, 15));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(20, 14));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(62, 24));
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(39, 84));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() { 
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                for(Iterator i=points.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                    Point2D.Float pt = (Point2D.Float)i.next();
                    g.drawString("X", (int)pt.x, (int)pt.y);
                }
            }
        };

        setContentPane(panel);
        setBounds(20, 20, 200, 200);
        setVisible(true);       
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scatterplot();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm).  This is a simple line graph example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Month");       

        final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 25));


        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can add a method to update the `stage` after the use enters the new data.

However, a better approach is to use the animation feature in JavaFX with the charts.  Straight form the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/package-summary.html):

> JavaFX charts lends itself very well for real time or dynamic Charting
>   (like online stocks, web traffic etc) from live data sets. Here is an
>   example of a dynamic chart created with simulated data. A Timeline is
>   used to simulate dynamic data for stock price variations over
>   time(hours).

There is a really good example in the API:

```
private XYChart.Series<Number,Number> hourDataSeries; 
private NumberAxis xAxis;
private Timeline animation;
private double hours = 0; 
private double timeInHours = 0;
private double prevY = 10;
private double y = 10; 

// timeline to add new data every 60th of a second
animation = new Timeline();
animation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000 / 60), new    EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // 6 minutes data per frame

      for(int count=0; count < 6; count++) {

        nextTime();
        plotTime();

      }
    }

}));
animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,24,3);

  final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,100,10);
  final LineChart<Number,Number> lc = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

  lc.setCreateSymbols(false);
  lc.setAnimated(false);
  lc.setLegendVisible(false);
  lc.setTitle("ACME Company Stock");

  xAxis.setLabel("Time");
  xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
  yAxis.setLabel("Share Price");
  yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis,"$",null));

  hourDataSeries = new XYChart.Series<Number,Number>();
  hourDataSeries.setName("Hourly Data");
  hourDataSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number,Number>(timeInHours,prevY));
  lc.getData().add(hourDataSeries);

  private void nextTime() {
      if (minutes == 59) {
          hours ++;
          minutes = 0;
      } else {
          minutes ++;
      }
      timeInHours = hours + ((1d/60d)*minutes);
  }

  private void plotTime() {
      if ((timeInHours % 1) == 0) {
          // change of hour
          double oldY = y;
          y = prevY - 10 + (Math.random()*20);
          prevY = oldY;
          while (y < 10 || y > 90) y = y - 10 + (Math.random()*20);
          hourDataSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(timeInHours, prevY));
          // after 25hours delete old data
          if (timeInHours > 25) hourDataSeries.getData().remove(0);
          // every hour after 24 move range 1 hour
          if (timeInHours > 24) {
              xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxis.getLowerBound()+1);
              xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxis.getUpperBound()+1);
          }
      }
  }
```